# decimal to bin recursion function python

Tags: python, recursion, printing

So I am trying to create a recursive function that converts dic to bin.
The only issue I am facing is printing a newline after the recursion is over.

I tried placing the `print()` in several different lines in the code, but it does not seem to have the effect I am looking for. For example, if the decimal is 13, I wish to print:

```
1101                   
#new blank line
```

The code I have so far does not reach the `n == 0` statement. I tried moving around the print with no success:

```
def convert_binary(n):
    if n > 1:
        convert_binary(n//2)
    print   (n%2,end='')
    if n == 0:
        print ()
```

Comment: Another approach is to just return a string and deal with that however you like.

Comment: How can I return the final value of the recursion? return 1101

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def convert2bin(n, end='\n'):
    if n > 1:
        convert2bin(n//2, end='')
    print(n%2, end=end)
```